# Drupal 7 Ajax Forms - select element

Tags: ajax, select, drupal-7

I've got a custom module form in Drupal 7. The code looks like this

```
function form_example_dynamic_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['tables'] = array(

            '#type' => 'select',
            '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array("2012", "2013")),
            '#title' => t('Select year:'),

            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'form_example_dynamic_myajax',
                'wrapper' => 'abcd',
                'effect' => 'fade',
                'method' => 'replace',
                ),

           );

 return $form;
 }

 function form_example_dynamic_myajax($form, $form_state) {
    return $form_state['values']['tables'];
 }
```

So this simple code should update #abcd tag with the value of the 'tables' select. And the problem is that it works only for the first selection. If I chose 2013 it returns "2013" text in my #abcd tag. But, when I chose 2012, an #abcd tag stays unchanged. It still apperas 2013.

Here is the example: http://kuzaj.yamandi.com/pl/form_example_dynamic

Does anyone has any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

So the 'method' => 'replace' attribute REPLACES whole wrapper into new text. Example:

There is eg div:

First choice (eg 2013) changes it to (note that there is no more an #abcd tag):

2013

Then again if the form element is changed it searches for an #abcd tag but there is nothing like that becouse it has been already replaced with "2013". So instead of using 'replace' method it should be 'html'. Html method replace content of tag, but the tag stays "untouched".